# Multicolor inside borders for polygons in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, polygon, style, borders

I was reading a report and I came across a figure that I quite liked the look of. I found that the author uses a black border for all of their polygons coupled with inside colored lines which just hug the outside borders. I have been trying to approximate this effect in QGIS 3.16 but have thus far not been successful.

Does anyone know if this effect can be achieved via QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make this with an outline symbole and an offset

[image]

Comment: I count 14 symbols in your screenshot.  Do you have to make these settings, one at a time, for every individual symbol?  Or is there a way to make the settings once for all 14 symbols?

Comment: @StuSmith. You just have to define your symbology once. Next, in the layers properties, you can change colors (or other parmeters) for every individual symbol if you want.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rather than using an offset it's also possible to use a thick outline an to check the "Draw line only inside polygon" box (last one visible your setting image)

Answer (score 6):

The process is simple. You need to do the following:

- Load the polygon layer and create a duplicate, by right-click the `original layer -> Duplicate Layer`

[image]

- Make the top layer a a single symbol with transparent fill. Click on `Simple fill -> Fill Color -> Transparent`.

[image]

- For the second layer, the duplicate layer, Simple Fill and change the `Symbol layer type` to `Shapeburst fill`. Select the color for the top fill and transparent color for the second fill, and change the `Set distance` to 3 for example.

[image]

- Last Step, Change the layer style from `Single symbol` to `Categorized`, and select the field to categorize. In this example, `Id` field was used, and click on `Classify`.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

**Update**

If you want to avoid creating a duplicate layer, change `Categorized` to `Rule-based` Style, then `Add Symbol` using the Green plus at the bottom, double click the symbol, select Simple fill, and finally select Transparent fill.

[image]

You will have the same effect.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to duplicate the layer. Try adding a second line / symbol to the dialog and otherwise following your method.