# Display each contact line for different polygons from same layer with different colours

Tags: polygon, display, borders

Any idea on how to display polygons as borders, but keeping both contacting borders, without gaps, and keeping the colours of each polygon? The polygon should have no fill.
[image: This illustrates what I want to achieve. The polygon should have no fill]

Comment: QGIS solution: [Multicolor inside borders for polygons in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378128/multicolor-inside-borders-for-polygons-in-qgis-3)

Comment: Which software do you use?

Comment: ArcGIS Pro solution:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiDMYTD3OCQ

Comment: I use QGIS 3.22.5-Białowieża. The solution for QGIS works as intended.